# I have an error with my eslint file (ESLint configuration is invalid)

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, eslint

I have an error with my eslint file. Here it is the error :

> "ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.js is invalid:
> - Unexpected top-level property "linebreak-style"."

Here it is my eslint file :

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:eslint-plugin/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
  ],
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {
    "no-restricted-syntax": 0,
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "padded-blocks": ["error", "never"],
    "comma-dangle": "off",
  },
  "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
};type here
```

and here it is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "p8",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.66.1"
  }
}
```

I tried to change mt eslint file but nothing changed.

Comment: What did you change in the eslint file?   It's clearly not liking ```"linebreak-style"``` where it is.  Taking a gander at https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/linebreak-style, I'm lead to believe that that part should be listed in the ```"rules"``` part.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.